# Converting a Double to UINT32 Nominator and Denominator in Delphi?

Tags: translation

Delphi: I want to get the Nominator and Denominator from a double, lets say 39.12, to UINT32 values:

```
val a Nominator = UINT32
val b Denominator = UINT32
```

How do I do that?

```
const dbFrameRate := 39.12;
Nominator := Trunc(dbFrameRate);
Denominator := Frac(dbFrameRate);
```

Frac returns the fractional number, but I need .12 translated to `UINT32(12)`

Comment: Multiply it by 100 and truncate. `Denominator := Trunc(Frac(dbFrameRate) * 100);`.